# DateTime.Parse throw exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, formatexception

I have no idea why exception was thrown, here's the working code:

```
DateTime.Parse("1/12/2012 12:00:00 AM")
```

And this is the one which throw exception:

```
DateTime.Parse("1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM")
```

Exception thrown is *"FormatException"*, include with this message:
*"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."*

Here's the CurrentCulture value:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
{en-MY}
Calendar: {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}
CompareInfo: {CompareInfo - en-MY}
CultureTypes: SpecificCultures | InstalledWin32Cultures
DateTimeFormat: {System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo}
DisplayName: "English (Malaysia)"
EnglishName: "English (Malaysia)"
IetfLanguageTag: "en-MY"
IsNeutralCulture: false
IsReadOnly: true
KeyboardLayoutId: 17417
LCID: 17417
Name: "en-MY"
NativeName: "English (Malaysia)"
NumberFormat: {System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo}
OptionalCalendars: {System.Globalization.Calendar[2]}
Parent: {en}
TextInfo: {TextInfo - en-MY}
ThreeLetterISOLanguageName: "eng"
ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName: "ENM"
TwoLetterISOLanguageName: "en"
UseUserOverride: true
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure there's not a typo in your code somewhere?  Also, check out the [DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, probably bitten by the fact that your culture uses dd/mm/yyyy format. There aren't 13 months in a year, only 12.

Comment: What is the value of System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?

Comment: @codekaizen which value of CurrentCulture do you mean?

Comment: CurrentCulture is a value... it is a CultureInfo instance. I mean that instance.

Comment: @codekaizen I've added the info in the post

Comment: Ok, yea, the date format found in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern is `d/M/yyyy`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because there are only 12 months in a year ;)

I'm guessing your current culture setting uses 'dd/MM/yyyy'. Either specify which culture's date format you're using for the string to be parsed using the overload of Parse:

```
DateTime.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)
```

or use the ParseExact() method and specify the format yourself.

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var format = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

DateTime.ParseExact("1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM", format, provider);
```

Comment: Either It's yyyy/mm/dd or reverse, and it seems that the year's last :)

Comment: +1 Good catch on the culture setting.  I was thinking maybe the compiler was superstitious and didn't like Friday the 13th :)

Comment: I've tried that but no luck, the very same date string i used in the parsing is actually converted into string from datetime in this very same machine, so I guess culture shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: Which one did you try? And how did you convert the date value into a string?

Comment: I've tried this: 

DateTime.ParseExact("1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Try: DateTime.ParseExact("1/13/2012 12:00:00 AM", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture). And I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: That is working now! I'm confused by the conversion, never get into this kind of problem before. Anyway, thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome. And to avoid the issue altogether, specify the format when you're converting the date into a string so you can use that format when you're converting back to a date.